# flutter can't delete library from pup

Tags: android, flutter

I tried many time to unistall webview_flutter: ^2.0.13 but still unable to delete it, even I removed it from pupspec, I need to delete it because im getting errors but I still see the package in the flutter plugin folder

[image]

Comment: please check the screenshot, webview_flutter-2.0.13 still exists

Answer (score 1):

1. Flutter pub remove webview_flutter
2. flutter pub cache clean

Comment: please check the screenshot, webview_flutter-2.0.13 still exists

Answer (score 0):

If a dependency is removed from the `pubspec` and then pub get is run, it removes the dependency from the `.packages file`, making the dependency unavailable for importing.

If a packages in your pub cache to change or break, you can use `flutter pub cache repair` command performs a clean reinstall of all hosted and git packages in the system cache.

Comment: still there and cant delete it from the flutter plugins folder